# Send current time in wlst to send to influxdb

Tags: python, jython, influxdb, wlst

The below script is an extract from

https://github.com/RittmanMead/obi-metrics-agent/blob/master/obi-metrics-agent.py

It is written in jython and invokes the weblogic scripting tool to send OBIEE DMS metrics to influxdb

However, I am facing an issue with the time format that sends incorrect time information to influxdb

```
import calendar, time, datetime
import sys
import getopt

try:
    wls_user = sys.argv[1]
    wls_pw = sys.argv[2]
    url  = sys.argv[3]
    outputFormat=sys.argv[4]
    targetHost=sys.argv[5]
    targetPort=sys.argv[6]
    targetDB=sys.argv[7]
except:
    print ''

print wls_user, wls_pw,url, outputFormat,targetHost,targetPort,targetDB

if outputFormat=='InfluxDB':
    import httplib
    influx_msgs=''
#now_epoch = calendar.timegm(time.gmtime())*1000
connect(wls_user,wls_pw,url)
from time import localtime, strftime
results = displayMetricTables('Oracle_BI*','dms_cProcessInfo')
for table in results:
    tableName = table.get('Table')
    rows = table.get('Rows')
    rowCollection = rows.values()
    iter = rowCollection.iterator()
    while iter.hasNext():
        java.lang.Thread.sleep(5 * 1000)
        now_epoch = datetime.datetime.now()
        print('Checkpoint 1 - Start of Data Load')
        row = iter.next()
        rowType = row.getCompositeType()
        keys = rowType.keySet()
        keyIter = keys.iterator()
        inst_name= row.get('Name').replace(' ','-')
        mcounter = 0
        try:
            server= row.get('Servername').replace(' ','-').replace('/','_')
        except:
            try:
                server= row.get('ServerName').replace(' ','-').replace('/','_')
            except:
                server='unknown'
        try:
            host= row.get('Host').replace(' ','-')
        except:
            host=''
        while keyIter.hasNext():
            columnName = keyIter.next()
            value = row.get(columnName )
            if columnName.find('.value')>0:
                metric_name=columnName.replace('.value','')
                if value is not None: 
                    if outputFormat=='InfluxDB':
                        mcounter = mcounter + 1
                        #java.lang.Thread.sleep(1 * 1000)
                        influx_msg= ('%s,server=%s,host=%s,metric_group=%s,metric_instance=%s value=%s %s') % (metric_name,server,host,tableName,inst_name,value,now_epoch)
                        print metric_name, now_epoch, mcounter
                        influx_msgs+='\n%s' % influx_msg
                        conn = httplib.HTTPConnection('%s:%s' % (targetHost,targetPort))
                        ## TODO pretty sure should be urlencoding this ...
                        a=conn.request("POST", ("/write?db=%s" % targetDB), influx_msg)
                        r=conn.getresponse()
```

Please advise

Thanks
P

Comment: You can use the strftime() function to format your date :  
`print now_epoch.strftime('current date is %d, %b %Y')`  
%d is the day number,  
%m is the month number,  
%b is the month abbreviation,  
%y is the year last two digits,  
%Y is the all year

Comment: Hi @EmmanuelCollin
Thanks for your reply
But unfortunately even though it prints the correct time information
It doesn't quite send it correctly to Influxdb
Perhaps there is a way to convert it to epoch_time through wlst?

Comment: as you send this information as a string, just format it as required by influxdb. For instance:  `fmt_epoch=now_epoch.strftime('%d, %b %Y')`

Comment: i just found that influxdb accepts date data in the form of epoch values only

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28589520/how-to-store-dates-in-influxdb

and 

https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.8/api/reading_and_writing_data/

Comment: But wlst doesnt accept epoch
when I try to loop the whole thing...
Is there any way to disconnect from weblogic and continue a python script loop?